# why is this url rewritten without first matched parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^^babysitter/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/? /hlp/index.php/babysitter/$1/?p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

So if I write this URL:
**localhost/hlp/babysitter/rome/3618**
the browser rewrites it like this:
**localhost/hlp/babysitter/3618**
which is something I don't want, even if it returns correct result.

For completeness I write my whole .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hlp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^^babysitters/([^/]*)/? /hlp/index.php/babysitters/?resume_location=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^^babysitter/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/? /hlp/index.php/babysitter/$1/?p=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hlp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: there are double caret **^^** in your rewrite pattern. is that a typing mistake?

Comment: To be true this rules are created by wordpress, so I wouldn't speak about typing mistake.

Comment: Well, the double caret is certainly _a_ mistake. The `RewriteBase` directive is also superfluous, since the path has been added to the `RewriteRule` _substitution_. This `.htaccess` file is presumably in the `/hlp` subdirectory, not the document root?

Comment: "the browser rewrites it like this:" - The rules you've posted don't appear to do this? Are you suggesting there is an _external redirect_ to `localhost/hlp/babysitter/3618`?

Comment: I tried it in another installation of wordpress, using a virtual host. The .htaccess file is in the root directory now but the behaviour is the same i.e. `dev.site.com/babysitter/rome/3618` becomes `dev.site.com/babysitter/3618` I also deleted the double caret

Comment: @w3dk I am studying and learning about mod_rewrite... I think that what you are saying is right, but if there's a redirect how can I verifiy it and eventually edit it? I think it comes from wordpress.

Comment: You're seeing the URL change in the browser's address bar - so this is an external redirect. You can confirm this if you look at the network traffic in the browser's developer tools (ie. object inspector). You should be able to see the status code. If you see a 302 that could happen implicitly (since it is Apache's default), however, if this is a 301 (permanent) then that must be an explicit redirect somewhere. Yes, this may be coming from WordPress itself.

Comment: Yes @w3dk, it's a 301 redirect, now I have to check where it comes from, any advice?

Comment: Solved! Found out where the redirect came from and managed it.